# Forward an email received in shared mailbox, setting FROM to a specific user account

Tags: vba, outlook, office365

I receive invoices from suppliers that I want to forward to a QBO (Quickbooks Online) email address that handles 'receipts/invoices' wherein it reads the attachments and parses the info within - this speeds up data entry.

QBO only accepts these emails from specific email addresses (i.e., ones that are registered as accounts in QBO). So assume that QBO only accepts emails from "me@mydomain.com". I receive the invoices on "billing@mydomain.com" which is a shared Office 365 mailbox that "me@mydomain.com" has access to.

My VBA code should forward the currently selected emails (found within the billing@mydomain.com mailbox) using the me@mydomain.com sending address to mydomain@qbodocs.com.

The problem is that the forwarded email arrives in the recipient's mailbox as having come from billing@mydomain.com. When I `.Display` (instead of `.Send`), I see that the sending account is set "correctly" yet it still arrives from the wrong account.

I decided that after the window pops up (using `.Display`), I would change the sending account to something else, then back to the intended sending account - and it works. So there's some setting/headers other than `.SentOnBehalfOfName` that I need to set as I don't want any user intervention.

```vb
Option Explicit
    
Public Sub SendToQBO()
    Dim Email As Object
    Dim Sender As String
    Sender = "me@mydomain.com"
      
    For Each Email In ActiveExplorer.Selection
        With Email.Forward
            ' Just send to myself for now until this is figured out
            .To = Sender
            '.To = "mydomain@qbodocs.com"
            .Subject = "Sent From Outlook"
            .Body = Email.Body
          
            .SendUsingAccount = Session.Accounts(Sender)
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = Sender
            .Send
            ' Using .Display instead shows the right sending address, but it's ineffective
            ' unless I select another, then select it again before manually sending.
            ' .Display
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to set up two properties simultaneously on the mail item.

The [MailItem.SendUsingAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sendusingaccount) returns or sets an `Account` object that represents the account under which the `MailItem` is to be sent. The `SendUsingAccount` property can be used to specify the account that should be used to send the `MailItem` when the `Send` method is called. Note, corresponding account should be configured in Outlook:

```
Sub SendUsingAccount()
 Dim oAccount As Outlook.account
 For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts 
 If oAccount.AccountType = olPop3 Then 
 Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem 
 Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
     oMail.Subject = "Sent using POP3 Account" 
     oMail.Recipients.Add ("someone@example.com") 
     oMail.Recipients.ResolveAll 
 Set oMail.SendUsingAccount = oAccount 
     oMail.Send 
 End If 
 Next 
End Sub
```

In case given permissions to the shared account you can use the [MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sentonbehalfofname) property which allows setting a string indicating the display name for the intended sender of the mail message. In that case the account may not be configured in Outlook.

And the last bit which I've noticed in your code:

```
For Each Email In ActiveExplorer.Selection
```

Remember, the selection object may contain different kind of Outlook items - appointments, posts, mail items and etc. So, I'd suggest adding a check for the item type before accessing `MailItem` methods and properties.

Comment: The thing is, since billing@mydomain.com is a shared mailbox, there is only one actual account accessible in Outlook via VBA and that is me@mydomain.com. So even considering that there's only one account that could possibly do the sending, it's still being reported as having come from the billing@ address. I think normally that's desirable/configurable behavior, just not in this case.

Comment: Also FYI this is an IMAP/Exchange account, not POP3.

Comment: There is no need to use the `MailItem.SendUsingAccount` property then. The `SentOnBehalfOfName` makes sense in Exchange profiles.

Comment: I've also tried just using that property and the issue persists. I believe ultimately it's because the forwarded email is from the billing@ mailbox so there's some sort of setting within Exchange that whenever emails get sent out from that mailbox, the sender allows the FROM address to show as from the shared account and not from the actual sender. I may be able to circumvent the problem by generating a brand new email instead of using Email.Forward. I'll post a solution if it works.